# MySQL 5.1 to 5.7 change Order By no longer working

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-5.1

I have a problem with MySQL creating a counter variable SOrder based on a set order defined by order by. It was working in MySQL 5.1 but currently not in 5.7. Original query in 5.1 had the subquery order by and was acceptable to the standards back then. Under 5.7 with only_full_group_by mode off, I added the order by to the outside but even when the order by within the subquery was commented out (or ignored according to SQL standards), it output SOrder as if it's random but not based on Column Carrier, PRIOR, ShipMethod, SingleModel.

```
SELECT 
    Carrier,
    PRIOR,
    ShipMethod,
    GroupOrder,
    @row_no:=IF(@prev_val = ANY_VALUE(t.SingleModel),
        @row_no,
        @row_no + 1) AS 'SOrder',
    SingleModel,
    COUNT(t.SingleModel) AS 'SingleModelTotQty',
    @prev_val:=ANY_VALUE(t.SingleModel)
FROM
    (SELECT 
        CASE
            WHEN ANY_VALUE(W.hdr_user_defined_field18) LIKE '%Fedex%' THEN 'FEDEX'
            ELSE 'UPS'
        END AS 'Carrier',
        CASE
            WHEN
                ANY_VALUE(W.hdr_user_defined_field20) IN ('16' , '26', '45', '88', '96')
                        OR ANY_VALUE(W.hdr_user_defined_field20) IN ('19' , '21', '22', '23', '24', '44', '76', '77', '78')
            THEN 'PRIOR'
            ELSE 'NORM'
        END AS 'PRIOR',
        CASE
            WHEN
                ANY_VALUE(W.hdr_user_defined_field20) IN ('88' , '96', '80', '97')
                    OR ANY_VALUE(W.hdr_user_defined_field20) IN ('76' , '77', '78', '79')
                    OR ANY_VALUE(W.`Ship-To Location`) != ''
            THEN 'S2S'
            ELSE 'S2H'
        END AS 'ShipMethod',
        CASE
            WHEN SUM(Quantity) = 1 THEN 'Single'
            WHEN
                SUM(Quantity) > 1 AND COUNT(`PO Number`) = 1
            THEN 'Multiple'
            WHEN COUNT(`PO Number`) > 1 THEN 'Mixed'
        END AS 'GroupOrder',
        CASE
            WHEN SUM(Quantity) = 1 THEN `Supplier Item Nbr`
            WHEN SUM(Quantity) > 1
                    AND COUNT(`PO Number`) = 1
            THEN ' '
            WHEN COUNT(`PO Number`) > 1 THEN ' '
        END AS 'SingleModel',
        `PO Number` AS 'PONUM',
        CASE
            WHEN SUM(Quantity) = 1 THEN ' '
            ELSE SUM(Quantity)
        END AS 'QtyPerMulPO'
    FROM
        dropship.Walmart_FullPOs W
    WHERE
        ProcessedDate = CURDATE() - 5
    GROUP BY `PO Number`
    **ORDER BY Carrier , PRIOR DESC , ShipMethod , GroupOrder DESC , SingleModel DESC**
    ) t,
    (SELECT @row_no:=0) x,
    (SELECT @prev_val:='') y
WHERE
    GroupOrder = 'Single'
GROUP BY Carrier , PRIOR , ShipMethod , SingleModel
ORDER BY t.Carrier , t.PRIOR DESC , t.ShipMethod , t.GroupOrder DESC , t.SingleModel DESC
```

Result
[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your `sql_mode`.

As of MySQL 5.7.x, the default sql mode includes **ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY**. (Before 5.7.5, MySQL does not detect functional dependency and ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is not enabled by default).

**ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY**: Non-deterministic grouping queries will be rejected

For more details check the documentation of [sql_mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)

**Method 1:**

Check default value of sql_mode:

```
SELECT @@sql_mode
```

Remove `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` from console by executing below query:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

**Method 2:**

Access phpmyadmin for editing your `sql_mode`

- Login on phpmyadmin and open localhost
- Top on **Variables** present on the top in menu items and search out for **sql mode**
- Click on edit button to remove `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` and save
  [image: sql mode settings in phpmyadmin]

Comment: I am not the administrator for the server but I did have the admin remove the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. Is there any other reason as to why the result?

Comment: @DunFletcherLin you don't need to be administrator, you just need to have permissions.
Is it still not working??

Comment: actualy I just checked once again in the system variables from workbench. The sql_mode is set to be empty