# How to find company name where salary greater than or equal to 4000 in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have schema like this:

[image]

I need to get names of companies where average salary is greater than or equal to 4000 where each distinct row of result must contain name of company whose average employee salary is >= 4000 as Company.Name format.

I tried this but its not working:

```
SELECT c.[name], AVG(s.salary)
FROM company AS c 
INNER JOIN salary AS s ON s.company_id = c.id
GROUP BY c.[name]
HAVING AVG(s.salary) >= 4000
```

Comment: you don't have to use `group by` since you are using `avg` function

Comment: What is not working? Could you put some example data?

Comment: Something is wrong with your question.  The documentation says that the salary values are between 10,000 and 100,000.  If this is enforced, then all companies with at least one employee with a salary meet the criterion.

Answer (score 1):

Recently Submitted this query. correct answer is -

```
SELECT COMPANY.NAME FROM COMPANY
JOIN SALARY ON SALARY.COMPANY_ID = COMPANY.ID
GROUP BY COMPANY.ID
HAVING AVG(SALARY.SALARY) >= 40000(whatsoever the amount)
```

Thanks, Lemme know in case of doubts

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your query is not wrong in structure, It only wrong in algorithm, you may group base on the foreign key. In this case, this is company_id, not the name. Anyway, I also test your code and success.

Can you share your error message clearly.

Cause I test in similar object on MySql and SQL is fine.

Here is my test code and site

```
SELECT AVG(A.PRICE),B.SUPPLIERNAME
FROM Suppliers as B
INNER JOIN  Products as A
ON A.SUPPLIERID = B.SUPPLIERID
GROUP BY B.SUPPLIERNAME
HAVING AVG(A.PRICE) >= 40
```

Site Code: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_avg
You may check and code in this first to test online.

Best Regards,
Huu Quang Nguyen

Answer (score 0):

Try running this query:

```
SELECT C.name, AVG(S.salary) as avg_salary
FROM company AS C 
JOIN salary AS S ON S.company_id = C.id
HAVING avg_salary >= 4000;
```

Edit based on the error shared:

Remove `only_full_group_by` from set value of `sql_mode` in mysql. After that restart mysql.

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62883266/4198180) to understand how you can edit sql_mode.

Comment: Error: `ERROR 1140 (42000) at line 6: In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'run_y3ppydde10z.C.NAME'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`